# How to remove user picture on the nodes

Tags: users, media

Is there a way to remove a user's picture from the node, or the teaser without any CSS modification, but just doing it from the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the settings for your theme. There is a check mark to include the user pictures or not. 
There are settings for the individual theme, and generic settings.